# Perl with inet_aton

Tags: mysql, perl, inet

My script is :

```
foreach (@missing) {
    my $ipdone = $_;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tbl_ips SET searched=\'1\' WHERE ip = '$ipdone'");
    $sth->execute();
}
```

And now we changed ip in mysql so it is in inet_aton format, so we would like to:

```
("UPDATE tbl_ips SET searched=\'1\' WHERE ip = inet_aton('$ipdone')");
```

but i can not make it work.

How should i do it ?

Comment: What's the column type of `ip`?

Comment: What's the output of `use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($ipdone));`?

Comment: btw, those `\ ` are totally useless.

Comment: Does the program die? Does `prepare` return a true value? What does `execute` return?

Comment: Please use placeholders for safety and correctness, and consider preparing `$sth` only once:  `$sth = $dbh->prepare('... WHERE ip = ?'); foreach my $ipdone (@missing) { $sth->execute($ipdone); }`

Answer (score 1):

What does "can not make it work" look like?  What happens?

One thing I can think of that might make the original query have worked but the replacement not do so would be if `$ipdone` had trailing spaces; those will be ignored in what `ip = '$ipdone'` would have selected, but will cause mysql's inet_aton to return NULL.